# Android , Persistencia Interna offline

Tags: java, android

Actualmente estoy utilizando sqlLite para algunas cosas , pero me preguntaba si existe alguna forma sencilla de guardar por ejemplo un STRING en la base interna del telefono sin necesidad de utilizar librerías externas , ?

Comment: Hola Bruno, busca en el sitio esta info ya se encuentra: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+guardar+datos también https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+persistencia+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos

revisando la documentacion de google hay varias opciones que puedes considerar aqui: 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html?hl=es-419

una opcion que veo muy buena es usar las shared preferences

```
SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("LLaveCadena", "string a guardar");

// guarda!
editor.apply();

// recuperemos 
SharedPreferences settings = 
getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String cadenaRecuperada= settings.getString("LLaveCadena",  "default_string");
```

en el link te puse existe la opción de guardar a un archivo fisico dentro de la app

Comment: Gracias jorge! , lo pondre en practica